# Firebase - function rewrites for client/server setup in 1 project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Fairly new to Firebase (and love it), but have scoured the web and cannot find a similar issue with a valid solution.

I am using 2 `firebase.json` files, 1 for my client and 1 for my server (both express apps). They both deploy a function each to **a single firebase project**.

Note: They are both express apps (client side is ssr react app, server side is node js api).

The problem I am having is that for the life of me, I cannot seem to redirect the `/api` path to my `server` firebase function.

This is my client-side firebase.json:

```
{
    "hosting": {
        "public": "dist",
        "rewrites": [
            {
                "source": "/api{,/**}",
                "function": "server"
            },
            {
                "source": "**",
                "function": "client"
            }
        ],
        "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "node_modules/**"]
    },
    "functions": {
        "source": ".",
        "predeploy": ["npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint", "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"]
    }
}
```

And this is my server (api) firebase.json:

```
{
        "hosting": {
            "public": "lib",
            "rewrites": [
                {
                    "source": "**",
                    "function": "server"
                }
            ],
            "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "node_modules/**"]
        },
        "functions": {
            "source": ".",
            "predeploy": ["npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint", "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"]
        }
    }
```

Whatever I do, when I navigate to www.mydomain.com/api it is only rendering the client side app not the API! Yet I have both the client & server functions showing in my Firebase functions dashboard.

So a couple of questions:

1) Why is this happening, is there something wrong with my firebase config?
2) Is it ok to use 2 firebase.json files for 1 project or preference to separate these into multiple projects? If so, why?

Thanks

Comment: I know the docs say that rewrites are matched against the first `source` glob pattern that matches it, but have you tried reversing the array?

Comment: It shouldn't be neccessary, but have you also tried an explicit exclude? i.e. `!/api{,/**}`

Comment: Thanks for chiming in, so the issue was that I was running "firebase deploy --only functions" which wasn't updating the rewrites (my bad). Also the array order is important, it doesn't work swapping them around but does with the original orders. Thanks :)